# преобразование файла формата json в датафрейм с помощью Python

Tags: python, json

Из Appmetrica, с помощью инструментов веб-интерфейса, выгружаю файл формата json.
Открываю его через Python и хочу преобразовать в таблицу, с кот. я смогу делать дальнейшие операции.

Использую такой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_json('C:\\Users\\Petr\\Desktop\\events.json', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', orient='records')
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 200)
df.head(20)
```

Однако на выходе у меня получается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидания были - датафрейм с отдельными столбцам (Регион, город, аптека, поисковый запрос)и и значениями.
В Python я новичок. Буду очень благодарен за помощь с решением этого вопроса.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1522746/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0/1522800#1522800

Comment: Вопрос должен содержать воспроизводимый пример исходных данных. Таковы правила. Таков путь.

Comment: Ваше решение подошло. Спасибо!